# Getting aws tag values and compare with regex issue

Tags: python, regex, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to pull budget codes out of tags on aws resources I have the following code:

```
for resource in awsresources["ResourceTagMappingList"]:
        resourcearn = resource["ResourceARN"]
        for tags in resource["Tags"]:
            if tags['Key'] == 'Budget':
                budgetCode = tags['Value']
                pattern = "^[\d]{3}-[\d]{4}-[\d]{1}-[\d]{6}-[\d]{4}-[\d]{4}-[\d]{4}$"
                result = re.search(pattern, budgetCode)

                if result == None:
                    print(resourcearn + " Contains an non-valid budget code tag.  The tag value is " + tags['Value'] )
```

When the code runs it keep coming back as with one tag coming back as invalid 070-0702-1-000000-5309-7000-0000.  I then go and run it locally with just this code for testing and it seems to come back find and it returns it as a valid number.  Is there something I am missing why my lambda code is giving me different results?

```
budgetCode = "070-0702-1-000000-5309-7000-0000"
pattern = "^[\d]{3}-[\d]{4}-[\d]{1}-[\d]{6}-[\d]{4}-[\d]{4}-[\d]{4}$"
result = re.search(pattern, budgetCode)

if result == None:
    print("Not a valid budget code")
```

Comment: Your regex [matches](https://regex101.com/r/sIYv53/1) the `070-0702-1-000000-5309-7000-0000` string.

Answer (score 0):

This regex `^[\d]{3}-[\d]{4}-[\d]{1}-[\d]{6}-[\d]{4}-[\d]{4}-[\d]{4}$`
matches this number string `"070-0702-1-000000-5309-7000-0000"`
so what's wrong is the string has some leading trailing (white) spaces in it.
For a test, you can add quotes around it when it is output.
For another test, remove the anchors in the regex.

Could also be that one of the characters in not the ASCII that it should
be, so it's like a look-alike and what's printed might be translated
to ascii by the console driver.